# JQuery get with API

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create web page that aggregates news from different content providers. I am using the API provided by https://newsapi.org.

I would like to retrieve names of providers and append them to list.

But I am doing something wrong and cannot understand what, it seems I do not send get Request.

Here is my Plunker

https://embed.plnkr.co/WKPPzmFGdrruuXzumog6/

And the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Spotify Breakout</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>

function queryApi() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    const searchURL = 'https://newsapi.org/v1/sources?language=en';
        $.get(searchURL, {
            type: 'sources',
            key: '0dcb4145d12f4a129cad2c7cfa52a2b9'
        }).done(function(data){
\            var names = data.sources.name;
            names.forEach(function(names) {
                          var nameDiv = $('<li>');
            nameDiv.html(sources.name);
            $('#nameList').append(nameDiv);
          }); 
         });
        });
}

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<ul id="nameList"></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you doing wrong? Is there a runtime error? Is your code's behavior different than what you intended? In what way? Your question is incomplete.

Comment: add all relevant code in OP not in an external link\

Comment: I added information, my problem it that get request doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code get data from API. But, the way you retrieve (parse) data from API is wrong. You better check how data is constructed before parsing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Spotify Breakout</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            const searchURL = 'https://newsapi.org/v1/sources?language=en';
            $.get(searchURL, {
                type: 'sources',
                key: '0dcb4145d12f4a129cad2c7cfa52a2b9'
            }).done(function(data){
                var names = data.sources.name;
                data.sources.forEach(function(source) {
                    var nameDiv = $('<li>');
                    nameDiv.html(source.name);
                    $('#nameList').append(nameDiv);
                }); 
            });
        });
        
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="nameList"></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```